# Custom Config Section

Tags: web-config

I am new to VB.Net. I have requirements that I need to create custom config section. I have read some documents but I can't make it work. Appreciate any help.

I need to read in config section with structure like this.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="reportingTabCollectionSection" type="mydll.ReportingTabSection, mydll"/>
</configSections>

<reportingTabCollectionSection>
  <reportingTabCollection>
      <reportingTab tabName="Parent Tab 1" visible="true">
         <reportingTab tabName="Son 1" visible="true"/>
         <reportingTab tabName="Son 2" visible="true"/>
      </reportingTab>
      <reportingTab tabName="Parent Tab 2" visible="false">
         <reportingTab tabName="Child 1" visible="true"/>
         <reportingTab tabName="Child 2" visible="true"/>
      </reportingTab>
    </reportingTabCollection>
</reportingTabCollectionSection>
```

Or like a structure of this class

```
Public Class ReportTab
    Public Property TabName As String
    Public Property Visible As Boolean
    Public Property SubTab As IList(Of ReportTab)
End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried checking: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 ??

Comment: yes, I tried it. I made it work, except for one more thing. I can't make it work if there is a sub element or sub collection